# Moving an expectation inside a probability?

Tags: probability, probability-inequalities

Let $X$ and $Y$ be two independent random vectors such that $E[X^TY]>0$, and all components of $X$ are positive valued.

Then, is it true that, $P_{X,Y}\{X^T Y > 0\} \le P_{Y}\{E_X[X]^T Y > 0\}$ ?

Comment: Taking the simplest case of vectors of length $1$, are you asking whether $E[XY] > 0$ implies that $P\{XY > 0\} \leq P\{\mu_X Y > 0\}$?

Comment: I forgot one piece of info: $X$ is positive valued, so I edited the question.

Answer (score 4):

For the simple case of vectors of length $1$, the question is

> For independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that $P\{X > 0\} = 1$ and
>   $E[XY] > 0$, is it true that
>   $$P\{XY > 0\} \leq P\{E[X]Y > 0\}~??$$

and the answer is *Yes, and in fact the inequality is an equality, with
both probabilities having value $P\{Y > 0\}$.*

To see this, note that
$$\begin{align}
P\{XY > 0\} &= P\{X > 0, Y > 0\} + P\{X < 0, Y < 0\}\\
&= P\{X > 0, Y > 0\} & \scriptstyle{\text{because}~ P\{X<0\}=0}\\
&= P\{X > 0\}P\{Y > 0\}&\scriptstyle{\text{since $X$ and $Y$ are independent}}\\
&= P\{Y > 0\}&\scriptstyle{\text{since P\{X > 0 = 1\}}}
\end{align}$$
while $X$ being positive means that $E[X] > 0$, and so we have that
$$P\{E[X]Y > 0\} = P\left\{Y > \frac{0}{E[X]}\right\} = P\{Y > 0\}.$$
Note that the condition $E[XY]>0$ was not used anywhere in the proof.

I will leave it to you to figure out whether this proof can be extended to
random vectors with more than one component. Indeed, without any
information about the distributions of the $X_i$ and $Y_i$ other than
that $(X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n)$ is independent of $(Y_1,Y_2,\ldots, Y_n)$,
 $$E\left[X^TY\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_iY_i]=\sum_{i=1}^n E[X_i]E[Y_i] > 0$$
where all the $E[X_i]$ are positive numbers, the quantity 
$$P\{X^TY > 0\} = P\{X_1Y_1+X_2Y_2+\cdots+X_nY_n > 0\}$$
seems to be difficult to estimate or bound.

Comment: $\Pr(\{X>0\}\cap A)=\Pr(A)$ for every event $A$ when $\Pr(X>0)=1$. Independence is useless here.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Alas, an event of probability $1$ is independent of all other events, and so independence is there regardless of whether one chooses to use it (as I did) or not (as you did).

Comment: Yes, but you call to independence between $X$ and $Y$ to justify this step, and this assumption is useless. You don't use the independence between $\{X>0\}$ and other events, you use something stronger, and useless. The result for $n=1$ is true without the assumption of independence between $X$ and $Y$, and you proof uses this assumption.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent OK, OK. Feel free to insist that as long as we assume that $P\{X>0\}=1$, then we can infer that $P\{X>0,Y>0\} = P\{Y > 0\}$ while refusing to acknowledge (or perhaps even denying) that maybe, just maybe, it might be the case that the event $\{X>0\}$ is independent of all other events, and in particular, of the event $\{Y > 0\}$.

Comment: I don't deny that. I just claim independence between $X$ and $Y$ is stronger than needed (what you seem to deny).

Answer (score 1):

The inequality for $n=1$ obviously holds, *even without the independance assumption*, because both events $\{XY>0\}$ and $\{E[X]Y>0\}$ equal the event $\{Y>0\}$.

For $n=2$, sometimes the inequality is true, sometimes it is wrong. Consider $n=2$ and $X_2=Y_2=1$, and denote by $F$ the cdf of $Y_1$. Then, using independence between $X_1$ and $Y_1$, one has $\Pr(X_1Y_1+X_2Y_2)=\Pr(Y_1>-1/X_1)=1-E[F(W)]$ where $W \sim -1/X_1$. On the other hand, $\Pr(E(X_1)Y_1+E(X_2)Y_2)=1-F(-1/E(X_1))$. Now take $X_1$ non-constant and such as $E(1/X_1)=1/E(X_1)$, for example $X_1\sim\text{Beta}'(2,2)$ ([beta-prime distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_prime_distribution)). Then the problem consists in comparing $E[F(W)]$ with $F(E[W])$. If $\Pr(Y<0)=0$ then both quantities are zero. Otherwise, by Jensen's inequality,  $F(E[W])< E[F(W)]$ when $F$ is strictly convex on $(-\infty,0)$, and the inequality is reversed when $F$ is strictly concave $(-\infty,0)$. It remains to show that there exist such examples of $F$ such that the additional assumption $E[X^TY]=E[X_1]E[Y_1]+1>0$, for example taking $E[Y_1]=0$. This should cause no difficulty to find an example of strictly convex $F$ on $(-\infty,0)$. However this is not possible to get an example of strictly concave $F$ on $(-\infty,0)$; in this case one could follow the same idea but taking $\Pr(X_1>\epsilon)=1$, then taking an example of $F$ strictly concave on $(\frac{-1}{\epsilon}, 0)$. 
I'm sorry my answer is not very clean. This is not a complete answer, I just hope these hints are helpful.

Comment: Okay but did you use the condition $E[X^TY]>0$?

Comment: @axk Oh no, sorry. I missed this assumption. I'll take a look later.

Comment: @axk I have just updated my answer. This is not complete and not very clean. Say me if you don't find precise examples showing both inequalities are possible, by following the ideas of my answer.